# @Value not working properly with @ActiveProfiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, spring-test

I have several beans using `@Value` annotion in my project.
If I don't use `@ActiveProfiles` and run test with config below,everything is fine.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: localhost,schedule_off
```

But if I use `@ActiveProfiles`,there would be exception says

> 'Could not resolve placeholder XXX'.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("localhost,schedule_off")
```

Why is that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is (simply):

[@ActiveProfiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfiles.html) takes rather a `String[]` than a comma separated string parameter.

So please try (the decently different):

```
@ActiveProfiles({"localhost", "schedule_off"})
```

instead (tested/works!;).

Answer (score -1):

how about [this](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4)?

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: localhost,schedule_off
```